# phpseclib Unable to request pseudo-terminal (SFTP)

Tags: php, phpseclib

```
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($ftp_server,225);
if(!$sftp->login($ftp_user, $ftp_pass)){
 print_r($sftp->getErrors());
 exit('Login Failed');
}
```

I always get:

```
Notice: Unable to request pseudo-terminal in /www/asizi/lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 2239 
Notice: Connection closed prematurely in /www/asizi/lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 2347 
Array ( )
Login Failed
```

My login is correct, if I make it incorrect I get just: "Login Failed" with not errors/warnings

phpseclib version: 0.3.1

I can't pass `$sftp->login();`

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What do the SSH logs say? Here's an example of how to get them:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#logging

Note the `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);` and the `echo $ssh->getLog();` lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error occurred because I was calling `exec` in-between of a `read` and `write` session.

You can not call exec when emulating an interactive terminal session.